# Size container Twitter Bootstrap on iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I made a responsive website with Twitter Bootstrap and if I use an iPhone simulator on the net or the build in responsive design viewer in the new Firefox the layouts fits perfect when resizing to an iPhone size.

When watching [this](http://www.volleykrant.be/) website on the iPhone I have big problems with the size of the container, it seems that it is changed to max 20px. How does it comes that I don't have this problem when resizing my browser window?

For those who don't have an iPhone, here is a screenshot:

[image: iphone view]

Comment: Looks good on my iphone 4. Did you solve the issue or do you still have this problem on your device?

Comment: Yes sorry I fixed the meta tag viewport, there was a small error in it. Changing it fixed the problem.

Comment: @SteenhouwerD Can you please post your solution because i am also facing the same issue

Comment: @Coder_sLaY I just changed the viewport to meta content="width=device-width" name="viewport"